# Определение сервера средствами питона

Tags: python, скрипт

Ищу **python**-скрипт, который анализирует сайт с целью выявления типа используемого **HTTP-сервер**а.

Напишите ссылку на любой образец.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, почему именно python? Задача, кстати, весьма нетривиальная.

Comment: на python'е, п.ч. начал его учить/

Answer (score 3):

С помощью плагина requests, можно легко решить вашу задачу.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://vk.com/')
print r.headers["server"] // nginx/1.2.4
print r.headers["x-powered-by"] // PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9
```

Поскольку HTTP сервер один на сайте, нет смысла анализировать все страницы, достаточно одной.

Comment: Это хорошо, если сервер такой честный и отдаёт нужный заголовок. А если нет?

Comment: Если сервер подменяет свой заголовок, то остаются только эвристические методы, см. ответ выше про nmap. Ещё частенько за nginx прячут backend-сервер для генерации динамики(чаще всего это apache).

Answer (score 2):

Готового, наверняка, нет.

Как вариант:

- nmap'ом сканировать 80-й и 443-й порты нужных хостов.
- curl'ом ходить на разные страницы сайта и парсить из заголовка поле Server.

Из питона вызывать его через subprocess (или аналоги).